# Unable to create Cloud SQL (MySQL) read replica (v5.7)

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql

I have been following the official guide for creating read replicas of Cloud SQL (MySQL) instances using Terraform, which can be found here: Google Cloud SQL Documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica

This worked well in the past, but as of last Friday, I have encountered an error that halts the creation process. The error message is as follows:

```
Error: Error waiting for Create Instance: set MySQL flags error: Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'cloudsql_dbheartbeat_paused'
```

This issue has been reported to Google Cloud Support, but I am seeking insights from the community in case others have faced and resolved a similar problem.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Update: I have attempted to create a replica using the console and I see the same issue.

Update 2: It appears that we are not able to create read replicas of primary instances which have been created previously. (Patch versions  MYSQL_5_7_42.R20230530.03_00 and MYSQL_5_7_43.R20230909.02_00).
If we try to create a new primary instance and then a replica with new patch versions, it goes well.